# Email for Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, email

Currently I am using 'Dekko' as my multi client email tool on my Ubuntu Touch tablet and phone. I know that it is no longer under support, both Touch and Dekko, but what options are out there for a supported multi email client on Touch?

Answer (score 3):

Dekko 2 is totally under support.

Also Ubuntu touch is alive and well. It may not have the level of choice offered by Android but at least your privacy is left intact.

The FDroid route is always an option but personally I wont trust anything android aside from the lower level bootloader code (have no choice but to).

Hopefully purism will come through and actually deliver the Librem 5 and we can get rid of them for good.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can say Ubuntu Touch is dead.

The store is going to be closed and the ubuntu touch image will not receive any security updates, soon. I heard that Canonical even forces to go back to the gnome desktop, so Unity 7 and Unity 8 will die, too. I don't believe that the community can go on supporting ubuntu touch.

This is very sad. I don't like so recommend any other OS for your smartphone. Nevertheless here is my answer to your question:

Maybe you could use lineage OS (earlier called Cynogen mod/OS). It offers a common email client out of the box.

Additional most of the users install gapps which include all google services. If had chosen Ubuntu Touch to avoid the use of commercial services you can install the free open source software app store FDroid.

There are many other operating systems, which could be listed here. But this one is the most popular one.

Comment: For the last few months I have been using the UBPorts version of UT. it is not bad at all and seems to be coming alond nice. Dekko is workibg on it, but needs some updates, which are meant to be coming.